# Get the url where we are redirected from in php

Tags: php, redirect

How to get the url where we are redirected from in php. I tried to print the value og `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Nothing is printed. In Fiddler addons, We can see the URL Where we redirected from. Can anyone help me, how to get the url in php?

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] it's that you need. Check your's Apache settings and try again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u'r looking for how to get url where user was before login.

Its $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Server request url return where last request comes from.